# How to get calculated data from Controller to View and display it (laravel)?

Tags: php, view, laravel, controller

i have a question again.. So, this time I need to send calculated data from my controller to view. 
I have no problem with send simple data, like:

```
// Controller
public function index() {
  $page = Page::whereAlias('products');
  $products = Product::all();
  $data = compact('page', 'products');
  return View::make('products', $data);
}

//View
@foreach ($products as $product)
{{ $product->title }}
@endforeach
```

But in my project I need calculate for every products discount, if discounts date is correct, show it as discounted product.
Also calculate rating of this product, reviews count and so on. I have all correct relations and models.

And in my project I have next code (i think it's not correct):

```
// Controller
public function index() {
  $page = Page::whereAlias('products');
  $products = Product::all();
  $data = compact('page', 'products');
  return View::make('products', $data);
}

//View
<?php 
$discount_count = 0;
$rating_count = 0;
$reviews_count = 0;
?>

@foreach ($products as $product)
    {{ $product->title }}
    <?php 
    foreach ($product->rating as $rating) { $rating_count++; }
    ?>
    {{ $rating_count }}
    <?php 
    foreach ($product->reviews as $review) { $review_count++; }
    ?>
    {{ $review_count }}
    @if ($product->discount_date_start > $current_date < $discount_date_end)
    {{ $product->price - $product-discount }} 
    {{ round($product->discount / ($product->price / 100)); }}% // discount in percents
    @else
    {{ $product->price }}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

As I understand all calculations must be in controller? But how..?
Thank you.

Comment: i'm not to sure that you can use PHP code inside templating engines? defeats the entire point of using a template engine...  also, you should do all logic inside controller and pass the variables to the view.. thats what controllers are for.

Comment: I know that, but I have no idea how calculate it in controller and send  show it in view :/ maybe can be used models in this calculations? srsly, I don't know :(

Comment: just put the loops inside the controller... and pass the data as variables to the view.

Comment: And if i get 1000 products, it's 1000 new variables? Or i something not understand? :) How can I add a new variable to each product?

Comment: I think there is something fundamentally i don't understand about your code.. you are trying to set 3 variables based on your products, `discount_count` `rating_count` and `reviews_count` .. just calculate and pass these from your controller, then products as the array or dataset you are currently doing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All calculations actually should not be in the controller or the view, but an additional class most would refer to as a repository, but that's probably outside of the scope of the question.  It would work in the view or the controller as well, but if you don't have a repository class for handling this logic, into the controller it goes!

Just loop through the products in your controller and add properties to each product you have for the data you need.  This is untested, but it should be close to what you need.

```
// Controller
public function index() {
  $page = Page::whereAlias('products');
  $products = Product::all();

  foreach($products as $product) {
    if($product->dicount_rate_start > $current_date < $discount_date_end) {
        $product->total = $product->price - $product->discount;
        $product->round = round($product->discount / $product->price / 100);
    } else {
        $product->total = $product->price;
        $product->round = '';
    }
  }

  $data = compact('page', 'products');

  return View::make('products', $data);
}

//View

@foreach ($products as $product)
    {{ $product->title }}
    {{ $product->rating->count() }}
    {{ $product->reviews->count() }}
    {{ $product->total }}
    {{ $product->round }}
@endforeach
```

You can also simplify your logic for adding up reviews and ratings as well using the `count()` method.

Comment: Thank you, for answer. I wanted to write something like this, but I was confused with 2 foreach cycles. It will not working slow down? If I have 1000 iterations?

Comment: I think it should actually be a bit faster not having to loop through those.